# Limit of a state-transition matrix

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, limits, dynamical-systems

Let $\omega$ be a positive real number and let $A,B\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ be $n\times n$ real matrices. Consider the following linear time-varying dynamical system
$$
\dot{x}(t) = (A + \cos(\omega t)B)x(t),\quad x(0)=x_0\in\mathbb{R}^{n}.
$$

Let $\Phi(t,0)$ denote the [state-transition matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State-transition_matrix) of the above system.

> **My question.** Is it true that
>   $$
> \lim_{\omega \to \infty} \Phi(t,0) = e^{At} \ \ \ ?
> $$

**Some remarks.** If matrices $A$ and $B$ commute, this is true. Indeed, in this case it holds
$$
\Phi(t,0) = e^{\int_0^t A + \cos(\omega \tau)B\, \mathrm{d}\tau}.
$$
In the non-commuting case, I didn't manage to prove this. The main issue here is that a closed-form expression of $\Phi(t,0)$ does not exist, apparently. The only (perhaps useful) idea that I had so far is to exploit the [Peano-Baker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State-transition_matrix#Peano-Baker_series) expansion of $\Phi(t,0)$. However, even with this tool, I couldn't provide an answer to my question.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: We can write the solution as $x=e^{At}y$, so we get that $y$ satisfies $y'=\cos(\omega t)C(t)y$, where $C(t)=e^{-At}Be^{At}$, and for the state-transition matrix $\Lambda(t) = e^{\int_0^t \cos(\omega \tau)C(\tau)\,d\tau}$. We see that $\Phi(t)=e^{At}\Lambda(t)$ and we must prove thus $\Lambda(t)\to I$ when $\omega\to\infty$, which seems true using integration by parts.

Comment: @user90189: Thank you. When you have time, could you please turn your comment into an answer (perhaps elaborating a little more the different steps)? So that I will be able to accept it.

Comment: @user90189 I'm looking forward to your answer. I'm interested, in particular, in the proof that $y'=\cos(\omega t)C(t)y$ has state-transition matrix $\exp\bigl(\int_0^t\cos(\omega \tau)C(\tau)\,d\tau\bigr)$.

Comment: $C(t)$ and $\int_0^t \cos(\omega s) C(s)ds$ do not necessarily commute...

Comment: @Ludwig, I was fooled by the form of the equation, I cannot prove that $\Lambda(t)=\exp(\int_0^t\cos(\omega \tau)C(\tau)\,d\tau)$. Sorry for misleading you.

Comment: @Ludwig, let me propose I way around. Integrating we have that $y(t)=y_0+\int_0^t \cos(\omega s)C(s)y(s)\,ds$, so we must prove that the integral on the right goes to zero as $\omega\to\infty$. We can try to prove this integrating by parts, but unfortunately $y$ depends on $\omega$, so we must get uniform control on $|y_\omega|$. We can do this using Gronwall's inequality, because $\frac{1}{2}(|y|^2)'=\cos(\omega t)(C(t)y\cdot y)\le |C(t)||y|^2$. Tell me, please, if you can complete my proposal, or I'm again wrong.

Comment: @user90189: I think the key is uniformity so you can using something like Riemann Lebesgue, but it is not clear to me. Using Gronwall needs some sort of uniformity as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me turn my comment into an answer: if we write $x(t)=e^{At}y(t)$, then $y$ satisfies the differential equation $\dot{y}=\cos(\omega t)C(t)y$, where $C(t)=e^{-At}Be^{At}$. We see thus that $\Phi(t,0)=e^{At}\Lambda(t,0)$, where $\Lambda(t,0)$ is the state-transition matrix associated to $\cos(\omega t)C(t)$. Hence, we must prove that $\Lambda(t,0)y_0\to y_0$ when $\omega\to\infty$.

To show this, we integrate the differential equation to get $y(t)=y_0+\int_0^t\cos(\omega s)C(s)y(s)\,ds$, so we must prove that the integral term on the right goes to zero, but $y$ depends on $\omega$, then we write also $y_\omega$. We integrate by parts to get

$$
\frac{1}{\omega}\big[-\int_0^t\sin(\omega s)(C(s)y_\omega(s))'\,ds+\sin(\omega t)C(t)y_\omega(t)\big] \\
= \frac{1}{\omega}\big[-\int_0^t\sin(\omega s)(C'(s)y_\omega(s)+\cos(\omega s)C(s)^2y_\omega(s))\,ds+\sin(\omega t)C(t)y_\omega(t)\big]\hspace{0.5cm}(*)
$$

We want to make $\omega$ goes to infinity, but we must first get a uniform upper bound of $y_\omega$. Take inner product at both sides of the differential equation to reach $\frac{1}{2}\dot{(|y|^2)}=\cos(\omega t)\langle C(t)y,y\rangle\le |C(t)||y|^2$. By [Gronwall's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%B6nwall%27s_inequality) we get $|y(t)|\le R(t)|y_0|$, where $R$ is a function independent from $\omega$. Use this in equation (*), to conclude that $y(t)\to y_0$ as $\omega\to\infty$ for fixed $t$, so $\Lambda(t,0)\to I$ as $\omega\to \infty$.

Comment: +1: Very cute. ${}$

Comment: Ingenious approach, thanks for sharing this! Out of curiosity, I was wondering if your approach can be somehow exploited to prove that for the (more general) system $\dot{x}=(A+\sum_{i=1}^m \cos(\omega_i t) B_i)x$, $\omega_i>0$, it holds $\lim_{\omega_i\to \infty}\Phi(t,0)=e^{At}$.

Comment: @Ludwig, I think it works.